# Visudo All Password Less Access to Script (Visudo + Cron)

Tags: unix, cron, sudo

I want my user 'dave' to be able to run a bash script without entering a password, so the script can run with crontab? For all other activities I'd like this user to be required to enter a password (as default). I know this can be accomplished via visudo, but I'm unable to get it to work. Wrong syntax maybe?

*My Visudo Entry:*

```
dave    ALL=(ALL) ALL
dave    ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/dave/thescript.sh
```

This works in the command line, I can execute it without entering a password. But the cron is returning `[sudo] password for dave:`

*My crontab for user 'dave' is:*

```
0 * * * * /home/dave/thescript.sh
```

Many thanks,
Ross

Comment: doesn't the crontab mention `sudo`?

Comment: @Gilles: The cron tab doesn't. But `thescript.sh`contains a line with sudo...

Answer (score 3):

Your entry above allows dave to run `/home/dave/thescript.sh` via `sudo` without entering a password.

You are not however running `thescript.sh` via `sudo`.

You will have to add a similar entry for the command that the script is trying to run via sudo to your sudoers file e.g.

```
dave ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/special/command
```

Answer (score 3):

The `sudoers` entry `dave ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/dave/thescript.sh` lets dave execute `sudo /home/dave/thescript.sh` without entering a password. It doesn't say anything about using `sudo` from that script; `sudo` doesn't care about what script, if any, invoked it.

If the whole script should run as root, then invoke it with `sudo /home/dave/thescript.sh` in the crontab. But then, why not simply put the script in `root`'s crontab?

Otherwise, if the script contains a line `sudo /path/to/mycommand arguments`, then put `dave ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/mycommand arguments` in the sudoers file. This will apply no matter where dave runs `mycommand` from.